# payment_intent_unexpected_state in stripe payment integration

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I am calling `stripe.confirmCardSetup()` for saving and reusing card details. I able to successfully call the API and can see the payment method attached to a customer in dashboard. However when I am trying to make the payment using `customerid` and `paymentid` I am seeing the below error:

> Message::You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method.;
>
> code: payment_intent_unexpected_state;
> request-id: req_9882186281261,
> Code::payment_intent_unexpected_state

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

i was using wrong customerid and paymentmethodid. My bad!!!